# Server not found problem on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: server, firefox, dns

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and the DNS can't find google.co.il. I've found a workaround - choosing to use walla or bing. I've found another workaround - changing the address to google.com. If it stays google.com, it works, but often it will switch back to google.co.il

To take an example; if I go to google.co.il/maps and change the URL to google.com/maps, the first glance of the map would come up, but it would refresh itself to google.co.il/maps and fail on a DNS problem.

It is hard for me to believe that google.co.il is really dead. My question is, as a work around, can I change firefox to use google.com in place of google.co.il? Is firefox changing the google.com/maps to google.co.il/maps or is Google itself doing that?

Comment: You can get around the redirect problem by using https://google.com/ncr - that `ncr` bit means ¨no country redirect". For the actual DNS issue, in a terminal, what do you get for `nslookup google.co.il` and `nslookup google.co.il 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1654918/comments/5 for a workaround. See its parent for the bug report itself. May be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail

Comment: I didn't realize that Ubuntu had a bug. I used: https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail

Comment: I used the answer which is marked as the accepted answer. The important thing is that my problems are over. I suffered for 2 weeks of sometimes getting a DNS and sometimes not. I suspect the bug will be fixed quite soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check your Firefox proxy settings:

1. Click the menu button and choose **Preferences**.
2. Select the **Advanced** panel.
3. Select the **Network** tab.
4. In the **Connection** section, click **Settings**....
5. Change your proxy settings: If you don't connect to the Internet through a proxy (or don't know whether you connect through a proxy), select **Auto-detect proxy settings for this network**

This worked for me